# When does 'If-Unmodified-Since' header prevent DML operations for custom Apex Rest?

Tags: rest-api, rest, apexrest

I have a *custom* Apex REST class that accepts a POST request and updates a custom object associated with the request. The inbound POST request contains an 'If-Unmodified-Since' header with the time it was sent (GMT.) Occasionally, the DML upsert operation will fail with the following error:

```
ENTITY_FAILED_IFLASTMODIFIED_ON_UPDATE
```

My question is: when the 'If-Unmodified-Since' header is included in a request to a custom Apex REST endpoint, will *any* DML operation fail on *any* record if the associated record's LastModifiedDate is after the 'If-Unmodified-Since' header date? Or is the comparison done against a different field? Is the logic different entirely?

Any information would be helpful. I can't find any documentation on this behavior.

Comment: I think it would be SystemModStamp, actually. But I don't see it in the documentation, either.